# structural type with upper bound?

Tags: scala, types

consider this design of a library I need to use and cannot fix:

```
trait Foo

class IgnoreMe extends Foo
class A extends Foo { def bar: A = ...}
class B extends Foo { def bar: B = ...}
```

In my code:

```
object Stuff {
  type Barred = { def bar: Foo }

  def doStuff(b:Barred) = b.bar
}
```

Thats all well and good except that the Stuff.doStuff will accept anything conforming to the type Barred, not just the subtypes of Foo I want.

I would like to define Barred such that it is both a subtype of Foo and has a bar method, and I cannot :( Help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply

```
type Barred = Foo {def bar: Foo }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
def doStuff(b: Barred with Foo) = b.bar
```

Another way to achieve what you want without reflection at runtime (but with more work if a new subtype of `Foo` with a `bar` method is added to the library), would be to define a `trait Barred[T]` typeclass, `implicit` instances of `Barred[A]` and `Barred[B]`, and use a type bound:

```
def doStuff[T : Barred](b: T)
```

Comment: I was going that way but didn't want the repetition in the signature.Interesting though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given your examples, this may be more suitable:

```
type Barred[T <: Barred[T]] = Foo { def bar: T }
```

This allows you to define, e.g.

```
def double_bar[T <: Barred[T]](x: T) = x.bar.bar
```

which @didierd's answer doesn't.